# sqlite column value back to select - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I have a quick question.  I am wanting to retrieve a value from my sqlite table (a specific value from a row in a specific column) and I was wondering how to get that value and put it back into a selectmenu.

```
$('#items option:selected').val(row['column1']);
```

This is what I have so far in my select statement for sqlite.  The #items is the id of my selectmenu, and val.(row['column1']) is the value that I want to get to put it inside the selectmenu specified if that makes sense.

I should note that I have successfully done this for all the form data, the values are being retrieved and displayed correctly, it's just the selectmenu that isn't displaying the required value.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, changed to:

```
$('#items').val(row['column1']);
```

then added this after the for loop in the sqlite statement:

```
$('#items').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

This correctly displayed the value from the table.